# How do I loop through a series of divs so that they appear underneath one another?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to imitate a guitar fretboard, and am confused as to how i can replicate the divs i have created and append ~10 more underneath. Each row is representing a string, and now i'm trying to append more divs with the same attributes to create an entire fretboard.

Trying to use a for loop that would loop the fretboard div I've created 10 times, but no luck:

```js
var strings = ["E", "A", "D", "G", "B", "e"];
var frets = 15;


for (i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
  var $div = $("<div/>");
  var $input = $("<input type='checkbox'>");
  $input.attr("data-string", strings[i]);
  //need to loop through frets to have data-fret = to fret number
  $input.attr("data-fret", 0);
  //need to loop through ids to create strings+fret num
  $input.attr("id", "E0");
  $div.append($input);

  //label should be same as id = string + fret num. for must equal id exactly
  var $label = $("<label for='E0'></label>");

  $div.append($input);
  $div.append($label);
  $('.fretboard').append($div);

}
```

```html
<div class="fretboard"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Any code related to your question must be **in** your question, not just linked. Links rot, and people shouldn't have to go offsite to help you. Instead, create an [MCVE](/help/mcve) on-site using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button in the editor).

Comment: I think I've copied your CodePen into the question, but I suggest checking it over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need an outer loop to handle adding the frets, while your inner loop (the one you have now) will create the strings for that fret.

This may require changes to your CSS since I have added a new `div.fret` to the html. Each of those represents a fret level on your `.fretboard`.
See this similar [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5r740q36/) for an example.

```
var strings = ["E", "A", "D", "G", "B", "e"];
var frets = 15;

for(var f = 0; f < frets; f++) {
  // create a new row that will represent this fret level
  var $fret = $("<div class='fret' data-fret='"+f+"'/>");

  for (i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
    var $div = $("<div/>");
    var $input = $("<input type='checkbox'>");
    $input.attr("data-string", strings[i]);
    // use f as the fret number
    $input.attr("data-fret", f);
    // set id to strings[i]+fret num
    var id = strings[i] + f;
    $input.attr("id", id);
    $div.append($input);

    // use id again
    var $label = $("<label for='"+id+"'></label>");

    $div.append($input);
    $div.append($label);
    $fret.append($div); // add to the fret, not the fretboard

  }

  // done creating the row, now append that to the fretboard
  $('.fretboard').append($fret);
}
```

And if you want the fretboard to display vertically, this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5r740q36/2/) applies the necessary style definitions. Give your fret div's the `fret` class name, and the inner div's the `note` class name. Summarized here:

```
.fret {
  display: block;
}
.note {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: I got a little carried away and added some [more features](https://jsfiddle.net/5r740q36/1/) including chord definitions. Feel free to add on if you find it useful.

Comment: @M.Claire Great! Nice project. If this answer solved your problem will you mark it as correct?